# How to sanitize user input for the gem acts-as-taggable-on, Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on

At the moment, my code looks like this:

```
@events = Event.tagged_with(params[:search_input])
```

But such a query allows SQL-Injections and should be avoided.

Rubyonrails.org tells us, how to avoid such attacks (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection)

For example, using questionmarks:

```
Model.where("login = ? AND password = ?", entered_user_name, entered_password).first
```

However, I don't know, how to sanitize the user input for this gem. I tried the following:

```
@events = Event.tagged_with("?", "%#{params[:search_input]}%")
```

But this leads to the following error:

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into String):
```

Any ideas, how to sanitize this input? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the `acts_as_taggable_on` gem is handling the sanitization for you.  All you need to do is pass your `params` value to the gem.  Try this:

```
@events = Event.tagged_with(params[:search_input])
```

Typically, you would use the approach that you were attempting when you interact directly with ActiveRecord.  In this case, `acts_as_taggable_on` is doing all of that for you, internally, using the query parameter mechanism.  The interface to the gem doesn't allow you to also use parameterization, which is what caused the error.

Comment: I found the following issue in the gem's repo: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/issues/670 Don't you agree or is it about something different ?

Comment: The issue seems to be different than this question.  This question asks about how to sanitize for use with SQL (ActiveRecord).  The issue that you linked asks about how to make sure that parsing tags occurs properly, and the recommendation given is to use the default parser.  These really are different concerns.